# Electric-lock control via NMOS matrix

Tags: digital-logic, nmos, pmos, matrix

Currently I am working on the design that allows to control 8x8 electric lock matrix via PIC16F877A.
As in comments for somebody it was not obvious (btw it was mentioned) I am using 64 electric locks in this design.

**Electric lock characteristics:**

*Supply voltage:* 12 V

*Sustaining current:* 900 mA

*Unlocking time:* 1 s

*Sustain time:* 5s

**Control section is described as follows:**
PIC->DMUX->INVERTER->(ROW/COLUMN)

In this design only one lock can be open at the time.

[image: part_of_matrix]

Reason I switched to multiplexing or better to say NMOS matrix is to use as small amount of MOSFETS as possible to reduce cost of the design and pins of PIC.

Single NMOS control looks like this:

[image: single ellock]

By using 1st DMUX I can control 8 columns. 2nd DMUX controls 8 rows, which gives us 64 possible controlled electric locks.

[image: Dmux+inverters]

As described above DMUX through inverter controls Gate of NMOS.

Thought about using PMOS to control voltage on rows but I don't know if it is a good idea and how to do it.

In order to prevent turning the gate of by touch I will use 10 kΩ resistor to GND between gate and source (NMOS).

In order to achieve best design I also want to choose appropriate diode which is not to powerful.

(Update)

a bit of a digging and found this schematic in "The art of electronics".
[image: aoe_pmos]

Combined with previos schematics it looks like this:
[image: matrix control]

I just dont know how to do an analisis of this circuit.
Coils represents the electric lock.
Tried LTspice without success.
Biggest concern form me is choosing apropriate PMOS.
Also I forgot about flyback diode between drain and source.

How to choose this diode?

Should I also use diode for PMOS?

How to choose apropriate NPN tranistor for this use?

How to calculate the changes of voltage and current in this circuit?

What about EMF and series/parrarel inductances?

In this case we've got only 3 series coils. In design there will be 8 of them in other cases even more.
Should I buy one of the electric locks and make measurements?
Is NPN+PMOS an efficent way to control matrix?
Are there more efficent ways to control this electric locks?

Tags were chosen like this because of lack of points to create my own. If it is possible please add good tags - will remove the bad ones.
Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question? If it's to make sure only one lock activates at a time that can be done simply by cascading demultiplexers.

Comment: I may have been imprecise in the question I asked. How can I control my matrix by using NMOS?

Comment: You'd need to use P-channel MOSFETs to provide power to the rows and N-channel MOSFETs to connect the columns to ground. You can't use high-side switching with N-channel MOSFETs unless you have gate voltage supply of at least 15 to 16 V.

Comment: @Alioth Please edit the question to add missing details: 1. The fact that you want to control up to 64 electromagnetic locks - that should literally be the first sentence. 2. That the locks have about 1A current consumption. 3. How long would each lock stay engaged? | Nowhere in those basic specs does the word "NMOS", "PMOS" or "matrix" figure. Those are specifics of a solution you have in mind, but they are not inherent to the problem.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The editing based on your guidelines has been made.